# pdf download file name issue

Tags: php, pdf, file-io

I am using the below code for secure pdf download. everything is working fine. the problem is downloaded pdf file name concats folder name also. I want to suppress the Folder name. Also provide any better solution for secured pdf downloads. Please check the below.

```
    $pdf_file = base64_decode($_GET['file_name']);
    $dir="Secured_files";
    $file = $dir."/".$pdf_file .".pdf";
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . urlencode($file));   
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");

    header("Content-Type: application/download");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");            
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
    flush(); // this doesn't really matter.
    $fp = fopen($file, "r");
    while (!feof($fp))
    {
        echo fread($fp, 65536);
        flush(); // this is essential for large downloads
    } 
    fclose($fp);
```

file name is : here  `Secured_files` is Folder name and `xxxxx` is file name.

> Secured_filesxxxxx.pdf

Comment: urlencode only this maybe -> $pdf_file

Comment: @Goikiu Thanks for ur response but I didn't get you what u r telling..

Comment: where you have -> filename=" . urlencode($file) try this -> filename=" . urlencode($pdf_file) , this will change the name of the file downloaded excluding the path.

Comment: U r correct. but, from url i am getting only file name. after getting the filename only i am  concatenating folder name manually.

Comment: Uhm... you can try and leave the urlencode if you want to show xxxxx.pdf (as your example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$file_label = $pdf_file .".pdf";
$file = $dir."/".$file_label;
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . urlencode($file_label));
```

Comment: is there any possibility to rename the file for hiding the original file name? this is just for security, not mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . urlencode($file));
```

with

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . urlencode($pdf_file));
```

`$file` is the full filepath not the name. You only want the name.

If this does still not work do a `var_dump($file)` and post the result.

Comment: both solutions are not working. for first one, there is no extension of the file name while downloading. anyway Stewie answer is working. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Ah yeah of course the extension is missing cause you encoded the full variable which includes the extension. I missed that :D